# PostgreSQL - How to search for text within a table column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called Students with a bunch of names and associated Id's. Eg

```
Id   |   Name
123      john
122      james
248      jake
```

I wanted to write a write a select query that would allow me to search for a particular Id.

I've tried

```
select Id from Students where Id ~ '248'
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting really confused by the official PostgreSQL documentation. Is there a certain way to write this query?

Thanks.

Comment: `select Id from Students where Id = '248'`

Comment: Voting to close as I doubt this would help anyone else...

Comment: Compare numbers to numbers, not to strings. `select id from students where id = 248`